# Load data with chunks

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, dask, chunks

I have some .zip files that are loaded to my database with the following code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
from dask.delayed import delayed
import sqlalchemy

connection_url=("mssql://xServerName/xDatabase?driver=SQL+Server")
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_url)
filenames = [r"\\1.2.3.4\logs\Det.2022-12-04.log.zip"]

for x in filenames:
    y = delayed(pd.read_csv)(x, sep='\t')
    df = y.compute()
    su= df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: 'Operation'})
    mask = su["Operation"].str.contains("xOrd|yOrd|zOrd")
    su[mask].to_sql('Detailspy',engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
```

The problem occurs when I try to upload a bigger file - the whole operation takes to much space.
Is there any way to split the file into smaller parts? I tried with chunks, but I get an error : "Delayed objects of unspecified length are not iterable"

Answer (score 0):

The lines

```py
    y = delayed(pd.read_csv)(x, sep='\t')
    df = y.compute()
```

are an anti-pattern: the first line delays a computation, the second line triggers the computation.

I don't know if `mssql` supports parallel writes, but assuming it does, the `delayed` wrapper should be around one sequence of `read-transform-insert`. In that case, by iterating over all filenames, the task graph can be constructed and submitted to dask scheduler for computation.